# Create a zip archive with a password

Tags: php, zip

So, I creating a zip file with a password:

```
function createZip($fileName,$fileText,$zipFileName,$zipPassword)
    {

       shell_exec('zip -P '.$zipPassword.' '.$zipFileName.'.zip '.$fileName);
       unlink($fileName);
       return file_exists($zipFileName.'.zip');
    }


    $filex = "/backup/home/fyewhzjp/long_location_of_a_file/temp/data/map10/data.txt";
    // $file_content = 'test';
    $archive = "/backup/home/fyewhzjp/long_location_of_a_file/temp/data/map10/archive";

    createZip($filex,$file_content,$archive,$pass);
```

And it works. I'm getting a `archive.zip` in my `/temp/data/map` folder on the website. But, when I open my archive I can see a bunch of folders, and data.txt at the end, let's say it will be
`/backup/home/fyewhzjp/long_location_of_a_file/temp/data/map10/data.txt`
So, I need to leave only `data.txt` in my folder, without other folders. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will face the same problem as I did, here is the solution:
Just add `-jrq` after `zip` in `shell_exec` like this:

```
shell_exec('zip -jrq -P '.$zipPassword.' '.$zipFileName.'.zip '.$fileName);
```

After that, full path will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Script47...

Pure PHP Available as of **PHP 7.2.0** and **PECL zip 1.14.0**, respectively, if built against **libzip ≥ 1.2.0**.

```php
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    // Add files
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');
    $zip->addFile('data.txt', 'entryname.txt');

    // Set global (for each file) password
    $zip->setPassword('your_password_here');    

    // This part will set that 'data.txt' will be encrypted with your password
    $zip->setEncryptionName('data.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_128);   // Have to encrypt each file in zip

    $zip->close(); 
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using `shell_exec` why don't you just use the [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class with the functions [`ZipArchiveOpen::open`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) and [`ZipArchive::setPassword`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php), it seems that that would make things a lot easier.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');
    $zip->addFile('data.txt', 'entryname.txt');
    $zip->setPassword('your_password_here');
    $zip->close(); 
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

> Note:
>   This function only sets the password to be used to decompress the archive; it does not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my native language, but do you mean that I can only use "setPassword" to decrypt my zip archive, and not for creating and protecting my archive with a password?

Comment: Why suggesting to use setPassword if it can be used just for decompressing?

Comment: note also that libzip must be >= 1.2.0 as noted above